# i think it is enough that only one kind of classloader in java

Tags: java, jvm, classloader

There are multiple subclasses of ClassLoader: BootstrapClassLoader,ExtClassLoader,AppClassLoader and so on.

However, I think only one BootstrapClassLoader is enough!

Can someone please tell me why there are so many different kinds of ClassLoaders?

**NOTICE: this is why there are so many kinds of classloaders, not why there are so many instances of classloader!**

Comment: i just want to know why!not for anything else!

Comment: liuxiaori. They were talking about the fact that you seem to never have accepted any answer on Stackoverflow as correct. There is a tick box next to every answer. Click the one you think is the right one.

Comment: i am so sorry! it is my fault! now i know what they say.and i have accepted the answers of the questions i asked.i am so so sorry

Comment: "I think only one BootstrapClassLoader is enough!" Why do you think that? What are *your* reasons for *your* belief?

Comment: @EJP i mean two kinds of classloader,one is BootstrapClassLoader ,another is custom classloader.and BootstrapClassLoader do everything that ExtClassLoader and AppClassLoader do.

Comment: @liuxiaori Then you should expound *your* theory in complete detail so that people can tell you what's wrong with it. Just asking 'why isn't the universe built according to my theory' doesn't really mean anything, or provide any real question that can be answered. The obvious answer to your question is that they all do different things, which are almost certainly documented in their Javadoc, which you should therefore read.

Comment: @EJP yes,i know what you say,i will enhance next time. i know their duty is different, i just want to know why not put them in one.

Comment: @liuxiaori *because* their duty is different. You could put every class in the JDK into one class but what exactly would be the point? Defining class duties and boundaries is a major part of OO design. The Java designers have done it one way. You think you might have done it another way. If you saw inside the classes you might change your mind about that. Starting with the presupposition that you are right and they were wrong is starting from the wrong end.

Comment: yeah! i accept the opinion of OO design.thank you a lot!:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each class loader is designed to load classes from different locations.  For instance, you can actually create a class loader that will load a class file from a networked server or download the binary of a class from a remote web server, etc.  The logic that performs this operation is baked into the class loader itself and provides a consistent interface so that clients can load classes regardless of how the class loader actually performs the loading.  The BootstrapClassLoader is capable of loading classes from the JVM_HOME/lib directory...but what if you need to load them from a different location??

In short, because there as an infinite (well, not quite) number of ways to load classes and there needs to be a flexible system to allow developers to load them however they want.

Comment: right,i know different classloader loads classes from different locations,i think just one classloader is enough,it can first load JVM_HOME/lib ,then JVM_HOME/lib/ext, last load classpath.

Comment: @liuxiaori no, it's not enough.  That would limit Java to only being able to load classes in a manner that Oracle (the creator of Java) defines.  That would be a terrible limitation!  What happens when somebody wants to create a new method of storing/loading classes? Or if there is a special circumstance that Oracle didn't think about/know about when they created the BootstrapClassLoader?  Notice, I'm talking about _ways_ to load classes, not necessarily _locations_ to load classes from

Comment: but if you want another way of loading classes,maybe you can implement a custom classloader.and i mean can merge ExtClassLoader,AppClassLoader to BoostrapClassLoader? and i know BoostrapClassLoader is not implement by java,now we don't consider it.

Comment: A bootstrap class-loader is made to only cover a limited number of locations, so that **it can be fast.**  If you consider 'speed of lookup' in the mix, it justifies as many class-loaders as are needed.

Answer (score 2):

What if you want a JVM where the class files don't exist on a file system, where the primordial loader expects them to be? For example, you're running an embedded environment where the class file byte code is in ROM or on a raw USB stick.

What happens if you want to fetch bytecodes from over the network (like applets)?

What happens if Oracle decides that class file byte codes are better stored in database tables (this could actually make sense given their ownership of both the Oracle DBMS *and* Java).

What if you want to only load up the byte code from a file system *once* and then just memory-map it to different processes afterwards for efficiency?

What if you want encrypted byte code, that people can't disassemble from the file on disk, that's unencrypted only by the class loader? Yes, I know that nothing will make the file truly secure, the idea of these sorts of schemes is to simply stop the "casual" cracker. I don't expect it will slow down the more serious variety for more than seven seconds :-)

Different class loaders are what gives you the flexibility to insert your own method for loading up byte code, including those never yet thought of, while still allowing fall-back to the primordial one.

Comment: yes,i am not mean can't custom a classloader,i mean the system's classloader can be only one??